# Android Uploading Camera Image, Video to php Server

Tags: java, php, android, android-service, android-camera

I am trying to capture image or record a video using camera and then upload to my server. On the server side, i used PHP language to read the file and moved it to a particular location.

This is the PHP script

```js
<?php
 
// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";
 
// array for final json respone
$response = array();
 
// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
 
// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;
 
 
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
 
    // reading other post parameters
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';
 
    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;
    $response['website'] = $website;
 
    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }
 
        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}
 
// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and then i got PHP error like this

[image]

i do not have experience in PHP coding, i want to know what's wrong with this PHP.

The android client is complete run, it can take photo and video very well, even upload is completed, but i got nothing in my server client folder.

[image]

[image]
There are my android code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Camera activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Changing action bar background color
    // These two lines are not needed
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.action_bar))));

    btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

    /**
     * Capture image button click event
     */
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // capture picture
            captureImage();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Record video button click event
     */
    btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // record video
            recordVideo();
        }
    });

 // Checking camera availability
    if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device does't have camera
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
 * */
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to capture image
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to record video
 */
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // successfully captured the image
            // launching upload activity
            launchUploadActivity(true);


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // video successfully recorded
            // launching upload activity
            launchUploadActivity(false);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
    i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
    startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ---------------------- 
 * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

}

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {
// File upload url (replace the ip with your server address)
public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://wangjian.site90.net/AndroidFileUpload/fileUpload.php";

// Directory name to store captured images and videos
public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Android File Upload";
```

}

**UploadActivity.java**

```
public class UploadActivity extends Activity{
// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private String filePath = null;
private TextView txtPercentage;
private ImageView imgPreview;
private VideoView vidPreview;
private Button btnUpload;
long totalSize = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);

    // Changing action bar background color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(
                    R.color.action_bar))));
    // Receiving the data from previous activity
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
    filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

    // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
    boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

    if (filePath != null) {
        // Displaying the image or video on the screen
        previewMedia(isImage);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // uploading the file to server
            new UploadFileToServer().execute();
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
 * */
private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
    // Checking whether captured media is image or video
    if (isImage) {
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
        // start playing
        vidPreview.start();
    }
}
/**
 * Uploading the file to server
 * */
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile(){
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });   
            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            entity.addPart("website",new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
/**
 * Method to show alert dialog
 * */
private void showAlert(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

**Manifest.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wangjian.klmeet_photo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wangjian.klmeet_photo.UploadActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is LogCat:

```
06-04 03:53:12.440: E/MainActivity(7920): <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function  gethostname() in <b>/home/a4256838/public_html/AndroidFileUpload/fileUpload.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
06-04 03:53:12.440: E/MainActivity(7920): <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>
```

I'm a newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated. thanks so much! And i will upload more details if needed.

Comment: Remove this line `$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());` and replace `$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;` this with `$file_upload_url = 'http://wangjian.site90.net/AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;`

Comment: Or try `php_uname('n')` instead of `gethostname()`

Comment: Yes! It work. i just put 'n' instead of gethostname() thanks for your fast comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gethostname()` is a function of PHP >= 5.3.0 and I believe your server have  PHP < 5.3.0 so instead of `gethostname()` use `php_uname('n')` or Update your PHP version.

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(php_uname('n'));

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    // reading other post parameters
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;
    $response['website'] = $website;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Ref. [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)